# TYPO3 - include a powermail form via typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x, powermail, typo3-8.7.x

In sys folder [31] I've created a powermail form with uid=3 ... but how do I include it in a partial with typoscript?

```
lib.powermailmyform = CONTENT
lib.powermailmyform {
    select.pidInList = 3
}
```

... in Fluid-Template Show.html:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.powermailmyform" />
```

And set Constants:

```
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.misc.addQueryString=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a powermail form in a very special way via TypoScript (e.g. for an implementation on every page), you should add a powermail plugin (with all needed settings in FlexForm) in a page (sysfolder is ok) and render this content element via cObject CONTENT.

Comment: The specific form created is fully functional and as of right now I implement it via the BE on a tx_news record detail page. But this way I need to add it every single time I'm creating new news record. So I want to place <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.powermailmyform" /> in the partial of news. Can you show an example for 'render this content element via cObject CONTENT'? I adjusted mine above ...

Comment: Since years it's very simple to render the content of a specific page on a marker or variable like:

lib.content = CONTENT
lib.content {
 table = tt_content
 select {
  pidInList = 123
  orderBy = sorting
  where = colPos= 0
 }
}